# class "mysqli" is not found

Tags: php, windows, mysqli

under the Apache/2.0.65 (Win32) PHP/5.2.13 Server ..
when i run CMD line and input :`php -r "new mysqli();"`
CMD return :Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in Command line code on line 1

then i configure the php.ini and remove the comment from the start of the line extension=php_mysqli.dll , and set extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext" , even i copy the libmysql.dll and php_mysqli.dll to c:\windows\system32.  but it's still can't work ..

and run it again and still failed.

i run in windows7 apache 2.0 and php 5.2

who can help me ,,thanks

Comment: Check if you have `php.ini` in you apache install folder i.e. `apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini`, if so you should edit it too.

Comment: have you installed this stack manually? Did you look into [WAMP Server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) - easy to use, all in one (apache, php, mysql).

Answer (score 2):

You set `extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"` in your php.ini. However you put PHP extension in `C:\windows\system32`.

`php_mysqli.dll` must be in `C:\PHP\ext`.

Comment: when i use 

    phpinfo(); 

the info list shows:Loaded Configuration File was none

it's means the configure of php.ini was not loaded, so it can't work..

so i open apache directory and change the httpd and add a one line :DirectoryIndex c:/php/

then restart windows 7 . now it worked..

Comment: now when i use script of phpinfo(); Loaded Configuration File was :C:\php\php.ini so it's worked .. and mysqli() was loaded success.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same problem, and my problem was that I had the php.ini-production and php.ini-development files. I had to remove the '-production' from the end of my php.ini-production file to make it 'php.ini'. Then, I had to make sure I had uncommented the 'extension=mysqli' and change 'extension_dir="ext"' to 'extension_dir="c:/php/ext"'.

Also, I originally had my php base file named PHP7, and so I changed it to 'php'. Not sure if this was part of the solution, but it's a step I took to get my mysqli library working.

Answer (score 0):

My Windows 10 installation of PHP 7.4.7 contains two files `c:\php\php.ini-development` and `c:\php.ini-production` (with details from one of them below). I renamed the first file to `c:\php\php.ini` and enabled the line `extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext"` (by removing the `#` commenting symbol at the start of the line). Then I was able to connect to MySQL, which was running through XAMPP on a `localhost` sever. Just clarifying that I used a stand-along PHP to connect to MySQL in XAMPP (which comes with its own PHP server).

From `.ini` documentation:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About this file ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP comes packaged with two INI files. One that is recommended to be used
; in production environments and one that is recommended to be used in
; development environments.

; php.ini-production contains settings which hold security, performance and
; best practices at its core. But please be aware, these settings may break
; compatibility with older or less security conscience applications. We
; recommending using the production ini in production and testing environments.

; php.ini-development is very similar to its production variant, except it is
; much more verbose when it comes to errors. We recommend using the
; development version only in development environments, as errors shown to
; application users can inadvertently leak otherwise secure information.

; This is the php.ini-development INI file.
```

I hope these steps work for you too.